# Ответ nodejs на доменное имя

Tags: node.js, сервер, хостинг

Помогите, пожалуйста. Взял пробный VPS хостинг, все модули установил для ноды. Но проблема в том, что сервак отвечает на ip:порт. Как сделать, чтобы он отвечал на домен?

Админы написали:

> Чтобы в браузер открывал, вам нужно настроить на VPS web-сервер.
> как это сделать с node.js у нас никто не знает.
> и помочь с этим к сожалению не можем."

Желательно через фреймворк `Express`.

Comment: а node.js на каком порту запущен? Он и так для вас web-сервер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback)***

```
server.listen( port, [hostname], [backlog], [callback] );
// where hostname - IP or DNS name

// e.g.
require('http').createServer( function(){ /* ... */ } ).listen( port, dns );
```

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а как теперь убрать порт, то без порта он не заходит?

  var port = process.env.Port || 8888
  app.listen(port, 'host', function(){
         console.log('Listening on' + port)
   })

Comment: Должен заходить. Без порта никуда

Comment: что значит не куда. В будущем все сайты при запросе будут выглядеть так, что-ли "http://site.com:8888" ?

Comment: Если нужно, что бы можно было зайти броузером и не указывать порт - просто берите 80 порт. Это порт по умолчанию.

Comment: @Zow - это то, о чем я тебе когда-то говорил ты не знаешь элементарных вещей. Для того, что-бы пользователь мог зайти по адресу `http://sitename.com`, нужно слушать порт под волшебным номером **80**

Comment: ![](http://facepalm.jpg.to/)

Comment: @AlexWindHope к сожалению я на бекенде полный нуль

Answer (score 3):

Я лично не давно столкнулся с данной проблемой.
Купил доменное имя. Купил `VPS` на `DigitalOcean`. А вот порт убрать не мог.
Решение кроется в изменении конфигураций `ngnix`.
Путь к конфигурациям - `etc/ngnix/conf.d`
В этой папке создай файл (имя можно любое, например доменное имя) с расширением

```
.conf
```

В этот файл нужно вписать следующее:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name site.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

`server_name` - пишешь имя домена
`proxy_pass` `http://localhost:3000` - `3000` это порт на котором ты слушаешь соединения. Соответственно можешь поменять на тот, который используешь в скрипте.
Когда все сделал, в консоли введи

```
sudo service nginx restart
```